# C# Homework Dice Game

Tags: c#, dice

Im taking and Into c# course and Im having alot of fun learning, however Im getting stuck on this one assignment--I have to simulate rolling a 6 sided dice/die 500 times (user must input the number of rolls) while displaying the frequency of each side(1-6) and % roll. In addition I cant use arrays.
So To start what I did was Initiate a bool to loop my code because I have to ask the user if they want to roll again. Then I created a variable for dice1 and set it to a Random number between 1-6. I tried setting a variable to a console readline that was equal to the dice1 to have the user enter the number. This is pretty much where I get stuck and cant move forward.
I know many of you are much more knowledgeable than I am so It'd be great If anyone could give me some advice.

Here's what I have so far:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Initiate Looping Seqence
        bool choice = true;
        while (choice)
        {
            //Display Introduction and Instructions
            Console.WriteLine("Welcome To The Dice Game!");
            Console.WriteLine("This Program will simulate rolling a die and will track");
            Console.WriteLine("the Frequency each value is  rolled Then Display a Session Summary");
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue.....");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("How many times would you like to roll the die?");
            Random randomNum = new Random();

            int dice1;
            dice1 = randomNum.Next(1, 7);

            int choice2 = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine();


            Console.WriteLine(dice1);


            int s1 = 0;
            int s2 = 0;
            int s3 = 0;
            int s4 = 0;
            int s5 = 0;
            int s6 = 0;



            Console.WriteLine("Would you Like to Run This Program Again?");
            Console.WriteLine("Type \"yes\" to re-run or Type \"no\" to exit?");
            Console.ReadKey();

            string option;
            option = Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

      // public static double RollDice()
      //{
      // was not sure if to create a dice roll method            
      //}

    }

    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Couple of things to think about when posting here: What exactly are you having issues with? What's the question? You can also read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to better ask your question.

Comment: This site is really focused on more specific problems - you'll need to at least explain how you think the program should work and provide an attempt at implementing that logic. If it isn't working once you have it a bit more filled out then come back for some help.

Comment: I would recommend to create a Dice Class with a "Roll" Method that generate your random value with the number of "Dice side"

Comment: Take a look here : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460654.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have a break, take my code ヽ(^o^)丿

```
class Program {
    #region lambda shortcuts
    static Action<object> Warn = m => {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine(m);
    };
    static Action<object> Info = m => {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine(m);
    };
    static Action<object> WriteQuery = m => {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Gray;
        Console.Write(m);
    };
    static Action BreakLine = Console.WriteLine;
    #endregion

    static void Main(string[] args) {
        Console.Title = "The Dice Game";
        while(true) {
            bool @continue = RunDiceGame();
            if(!@continue) {
                break;
            }
            Console.Clear();
        }
    }

    static bool RunDiceGame() {
        //Display Introduction and Instructions
        Info("Welcome To The Dice Game!");
        Info("This Program will simulate rolling a dice and keeps track of the results");
        BreakLine();

        WriteQuery("Dice roll count: ");
        int rollCount = ReadInt32();

        WriteQuery("Random number generator seed: ");
        Random rng = new Random(ReadInt32());

        BreakLine();
        BreakLine();

        //map dice value to dice count
        var diceValues = new Dictionary<int, int>((int)rollCount);
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            diceValues.Add(i, 0);
        }

        //roll dice
        for(int i = 0; i < rollCount; i++) {
            int diceValue = rng.Next(6); //roll 0..5
            diceValues[diceValue]++;
        }

        //print results
        for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            int valueRollAbsolute = diceValues[i];
            double valueRollCountRelative = valueRollAbsolute / (double) rollCount;
            Info(string.Format("Value: {0}\tCount: {1:0,0}\tPercentage: {2:0%}", i + 1, valueRollAbsolute, valueRollCountRelative));
        }

        BreakLine();
        BreakLine();

        WriteQuery("Type 'yes' to restart, 'no' to exit.");
        BreakLine();
        return ReadYesNo();
    }

    #region console read methods
    static int ReadInt32() {
        while(true) {
            string input = Console.ReadLine();
            try {
                return Convert.ToInt32(input);
            } catch(FormatException) {
                Warn("Not a number: " + input);
            }
        }
    }

    static bool ReadYesNo() {
        while(true) {
            string option = Console.ReadLine();
            switch(option.ToLowerInvariant()) {
                case "yes":
                    return true;
                case "no":
                    return false;
                default:
                    Warn("Invalid option: " + option);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: A downvote-Ninja has appeared and landed a critical hit on my precious post! There's still 1 HP left...

Comment: thanks man! this will really help. I just have to switch a couple of things around.

Answer (score -2):

Here is some code to simulate the rolls & get how many times a number popped up

```
int rollAmount = 500;
int dice;
int s1 = 0;
int s2 = 0;
int s3 = 0;
int s4 = 0;
int s5 = 0;
int s6 = 0;
Random random = new Random();
for(int i = 0; i <= rollAmount; i++){
    dice = random.next(1,7);
    Console.Writeline("Roll " + i + ": " + dice.ToString());
    if(dice == 1) s1++;
    else if(dice == 2) s2++;
    else if(dice == 3) s3++;
    ...
}
Console.Writeline("1 Percentage: " + ((s1 / rollAmount) * 100) + "%");
Console.Writeline("2 Percentage: " + ((s2 / rollAmount) * 100) + "%");
Console.Writeline("3 Percentage: " + ((s3 / rollAmount) * 100) + "%");
...
Console.Writeline("Done");
```

Comment: chuck a readline at the end so the console window doesn't close

Comment: its c#, it won't close. Edit: Implying it windows form applications

Comment: I prefer `#ReadKey(true)`

Comment: @i'KeiAmuquadoh when they start `static void Main(string[] args)` it just reads console application to me not winforms

Comment: You are absolutely correctly, I read C# and just assumed. My bad.